# How to get requested target of Prometheus exporter (python)

Tags: python, prometheus, exporter

I'm writing a DNS server exporter in Python. Like SNMP exporter (https://github.com/prometheus/snmp_exporter), It can scrapes multiple IP targets. The http request will be like this: http://localhost:9522/metrics?module=dns&target=10.192.192.92. After received this request, the exporter will login to DNS server has OAM address of 10.192.192.92 and execute some commands to get metrics from that DNS server. The exporter code is like this:

```
from prometheus_client.core import GaugeMetricFamily, REGISTRY
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, MetricsHandler
class CustomCollector(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def collect(self):
        # Get target DNS server and then SSH to it and do some command to get some metrics
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = start_http_server(8003)
    REGISTRY.register(CustomCollector())
    print(type(server))
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

I'm stuck in how to get the target DNS server(e.g.:10.192.192.92). In Prometheus Python description https://github.com/prometheus/client_python, it said MetricsHandler class can help to get this value from request http address but I don't know how to code using this. Please help me to solve this headache problem. Thank you!